# Ruby/Rack/Sinatra encoding of a MessagePack POST

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, msgpack, messagepack

I am trying to build an API with Sinatra and MessagePack but I am about to shoot myself :)

So I am using curl to do a POST:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-msgpack" --data-binary '\x82\xA4uuid\xBD8asd76a-a8s7a6d87-asd76as8d76\xABcampaign_id\xA12' http://localhost:9393/
```

Now in Sinatra I just do:

```
MessagePack.unpack request.body.read
```

And this leads to the following error:

```
MessagePack::MalformedFormatError Exception: extra bytes follow after a deserialized object
```

Because request.body.read is returning:

```
"\\x82\\xA4uuid\\xBD8asd76a-a8s7a6d87-asd76as8d76\\xABcampaign_id\\xA12"

instead of
"\x82\xA4uuid\xBD8asd76a-a8s7a6d87-asd76as8d76\xABcampaign_id\xA12"
```

I tried everything I could think of like force_encoding(Encode::BINARY) and other stupid things. And I am not sure who is causing the problem ruby, rack or sinatra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is what you expect `curl --data-binary` to do from the command line. It does not process `'\x82'` into a byte value using Ruby-like syntax. It posts the characters as-is (which looks like `"\\x82"` if you inspect the string in Ruby).

Use the `@filename` syntax for curl instead, and save a data file that you have generated using MessagePack instead (make sure to set the mode to `'wb'` in Ruby):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-msgpack" --data-binary @test.dat http://localhost:9393/
```

Ruby to create test file:

```
msg = MessagePack.pack( 
  "uuid" => "8asd76a-a8s7a6d87-asd76as8d76", 
  "campaign_id" => "2"
) 
File.open( 'test.dat', 'wb' ) do |file|
  file.write( msg )
end
```